# ostream double precision

Tags: c++, precision, ostream

So I've implemented my own `array` data structure. I've implemented operations such as:

1. Adding an element on a specified index
2. Removing an element --------||--------
3. Checking if the value exists in array

Now I have to measure the time for these operations. I've got this code: (im using Visual Studio C++)

```
LARGE_INTEGER clock, start, end, result;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&clock);
int sizes[] = { 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000 };
long double seconds;
long double summedSeconds = 0;
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("results.txt");
std::setprecision(10); //I want the precision to be 1ns + 1 bit for rounding
for (auto&x : sizes)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
    {                   
        myArray.generate(x); // this generates myArray of size x
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
        myArray.insert(1, x / 2); //this will insert value of 1 into an index = half of array
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
        result.QuadPart = end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart;
        seconds = (long double)result.QuadPart / (long double)clock.QuadPart;
        summedSeconds += seconds; // this is summed up for 100 example data                 
    }
    std::cout << summedSeconds/100 << '\n';

    myfile << std::fixed << std::setw(6) << x << "\t" << summedSeconds/100 << '\n';
}
myfile.close();
```

Now, this gives me something like this in `results.txt`:

```
   100  0.000008
   200  0.000013
   500  0.000031
  1000  0.000052
  2000  0.000115
  5000  0.000287
 10000  0.000568
 20000  0.001134
 50000  0.002017
100000  0.003756
```

So based on the number of elements, the time is measured. But the lecturer wants `~1ns` precision, so that's not enough (now it's only 6 bits, I want at least 9-10). When I wasn't already saving it to a file, I was `cout`ing that information using `std::fixed` and `std::cout.precision(10)`. And it worked as I wanted. How can I make it work for saving to a file?

P.S I unfortunately cannot use `boost::`

Comment: Whoever told you that `precision()` doesn't work with `std::ofstream`, that you're using, was obviously wrong.

Comment: But then it was `std::cout.precision(10)`, now should I replace `cout` with something?

@Edit, okay you are right. `myfile.precision()` did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same manipulators that you've used with `cout` can be used with `fstreams` without any problems. Try using the same code you've used when printing to standard output.